# Error exit delayed from previous error

Tags: linux, shell, gzip, tar

I am trying to find the files in a directory and then gzip and then tar it .

The script :

```
find /home -type f -name "*.log" -newer /home/path/start_date \
    ! -newer /home/path/end_date | xargs -0 tar -cvzf files.tar.gz
```

The tar is still created but I am getting some errors :

```
tar:/home/path/filename.log\n Cannot stat : No such file or directory
tar:Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Can someone explain what are these errors? Thanks.

Comment: If you use `xargs -0`, then you need to use `find -print0`...

Comment: find /home -type f -name "*.log" -newer /home/path/start_date ! -newer /home/path/end_date -print0| xargs -0 tar -cvzf files.tar.gz .... do you mean like this?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `-print0`.

> -print0
>
> True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a
>   null character (instead of the newline character   that -print uses). 
>   This allows file names that contain newlines or other types of white
>   space to be correctly inter‐   preted by programs that process the
>   find output.  This option corresponds to the -0 option of xargs.

Also quote your exclamation mark to prevent history expansion just in case:

```
find /home -type f -name "*.log" -newer /home/path/start_date \! -newer /home/path/end_date -print0 | xargs -0 tar -cvzf files.tar.gz
```

It's not POSIX but if you can use `-not`, use `-not` instead:

```
... -not -newer ...
```

Comment: I tried doing that, I got this : tar :Removing leading '/' from member names

Comment: Also there`s one more thing , when I try to unzip the tar, it AGAIN creates the parent directory and subdirectories and then extracts . for example : it creates home/path/template/log1.log (the home ..path..template directories are created again inside my template directory).

Comment: @Kshitiz Tar by default strips it and it's normal but you can prevent that with `-P` or `--absolute-names` (`don't strip leading '/'s from file names`).

Comment: @Kshitiz How exactly do you want to store your files? Do you want that no directories are included?

Comment: konsole , I saw the posts , but I could not figure it out where to put -p .Sorry about that , I am still learning shell scripting.

Comment: I only need to gzip and tar the files and store anywhere remotely but I dont understand why does it creates the directory structure when I untar it.

Comment: @Kshitiz Tar behaves that way. It creates directory structure when it creates the archive and also creates directory structure when it extracts. It's probably by design so that it won't bother itself what to do when files with same filenames collide.

Comment: If you want to extract files without directories, you can refer to here: http://superuser.com/questions/71846/tar-extract-discarding-directory-structure

Comment: Thanks .Got it .Understood and how do I remove that leading '/' from member namEs. Where to put -p?

Comment: @Kshitiz `... | tar -P -cvzf files.tar.gz`. You really sure you really want to include `/`? You can just ignore the message.